# Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to convert all array elements to `null` if some are `undefined`:

```
console.log(MyThing[7]); //undefined.

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  if ($(".row.mine") != null) {
    if (typeof MyThing[i] === undefined) {
      MyThing[i] = null;
    } else {
      MyThing[i] = MyThing[i].replace(/Aa.*/, '').replace("-", "");
    }
  } else {
    if (typeof MyThing[i] === undefined) {
      MyThing[i] = null;
    }
  }
}
```

But that gives me an error `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`. So the elements are not converted if they are `undefined`. How should I change my code to achieve this?

Comment: try to set `undefined` into quotes => `'undefined'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typeof MyThing[i] === undefined` is always false, as the typeof operator always returns a string. Use one of the following:

```
typeof MyThing[i] === 'undefined'
MyThing[i] === undefined
```

Also this does not check if the value is `null` (as `typeof null === 'object'`). As I see you can have null values, so the next error you encounter will be probably `Cannot read property 'replace' of null`.

I suggest you to check directly for string type:

```
if ($(".row.mine") != null) {
  if (typeof MyThing[i] !== 'string') {
    MyThing[i] = null;
  } else {
    MyThing[i] = MyThing[i].replace(/Aa.*/, '').replace("-", "");
  }
} else {
  if (typeof MyThing[i] !== 'string') {
    MyThing[i] = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`typeof MyThing[i] === undefined` should be `MyThing[i] === undefined` or `typeof MyThing[i] === 'undefined'`, as `typeof` always gives you a *string*.

But in your context, I'd just use the fact that `undefined` is falsey:

```
if (!MyThing[i]) {
  MyThing[i] = null;
} else {
  MyThing[i] = MyThing[i].replace(/Aa.*/, '').replace("-", "");
}
```

**unless** `MyThing[i]` might be `""` and you don't want that converted to `null`.

Or expressing it in the positive:

```
if (MyThing[i]) {
  MyThing[i] = MyThing[i].replace(/Aa.*/, '').replace("-", "");
} else {
  MyThing[i] = null;
}
```

But again, note the thing about `""`.

Comment: @TJ, `if (MyThing[i]) ` will return true for `'undefined'` as well.

Comment: @Rajesh: Of course it will, and `replace` would work on that, as it's a string. But I don't think the OP has `'undefined'` in the array, just `undefined` and `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a typo error, try putting undefined inside a quote:

```
 if (typeof MyThing[i] === 'undefined') {
```